# How to efficiently seek in video files with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, seek

I want to make a common video player with opencv C++. Users should be able to freely move between frames of the video(commonly slider). So I simply wrote and tested two methods and both has problems.

My first solution:

```
int frameIdx = 0; /// This is accessed by other thread

cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");
while (true) {
  cv::Mat frame;
  cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameIdx);
  cap.read(frame);
  showFrameToWindow(frame);
  frameIdx++;
}
```

My second solution:

```
int frameIdx = 0; /// This is accessed by other thread
 
std::vector<cv::Mat> buffer;

cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4")
while (true) {
  cv::Mat frame;
  cap >> frame; 
  if (frame.empty()) break;
  buffer.push_back(frame);
}

while (true) {
  cv::Mat frame = buffer[frameIdx].clone();
  showFrameToWindow(frame);
  frameIdx++;
}
```

The first solution is too slow. I think there is an overhead `cap.read(cv::Mat)`. It's not possible to play video more than 20~30fps in my computer.
The second solution, it is satisfactory for speed, but it requires a lot of memory space.
So I imagine what if I change `std::vector` to `std::queue` of the `buffer`, limit its size, and update it in other thread while playing the video.
I'm not sure it's gonna work, and I wonder there's an common algorithm to seek in large video file. Any comments will save me. Thanks.

---

I developed my second solution to limitied size of frame buffer and handling it with other thread.

```
/// These variables are accessed from all threads.
#define BUF_MAX 64
bool s_videoFileLoaded;
double s_videoFileHz; // milliseconds per frame
int s_videoFileFrameCount;
bool s_seek;
int s_seekingIndex; // indexing video file, binded with UI
std::queue<cv::Mat> s_frameBuffer;
std::queue<int> s_indexBuffer;
std::mutex s_mtx;
///
/// !!! When seeking slider in UI moved manually,
/// !!! @s_seek turns to True.
/// 
/// Start of main thread.
cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");
s_videoFileLoaded = true;
s_videoFileFrameCount = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
s_videoFileHz = 1000.0 / cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);
s_seekingIndex = 0;

runThread( std::bind(&_videoHandlingThreadLoop, cap) );

Timer timer;
while (s_videoFileLoaded) {
    timer.restart();
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mtx);
        if (s_frameBuffer.empty())
            continue;
        cv::Mat frame = s_frameBuffer.front();
        s_seekingIndex = s_indexBuffer.front();
        s_frameBuffer.pop();
        s_indexBuffer.pop();
        showFrameToWindow(frame);
    }
    int remain = s_videoFileHz - timer.elapsed();
    if (remain > 0) Sleep(remain);
}
```

```
void _videoHandlingThreadLoop(cv::VideoCapture& cap) {
    s_seek = true;
    int frameIndex = -1;
    while (s_videoFileLoaded) {
        if (s_frameBuffer.size() > BUF_MAX) { 
            Sleep(s_videoFileHz * BUF_MAX);
            continue;
        }

        // Check whether it's time to 'seeking'.
        if (s_seek) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mtx);

            // Clear buffer
            s_frameBuffer = std::queue<cv::Mat>(); 
            s_indexBuffer = std::queue<int>();
            
            frameIndex = s_seekingIndex;
            cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameIndex);
            s_seek = false;
        }
        
        // Read frame from the file and push to buffer.
        cv::Mat frame;
        if (cap.read(frame)) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mtx);
            s_frameBuffer.push(frame);
            s_indexBuffer.push(frameIndex);
            frameIndex++;
        }

        // Check whether the frame is end of the file.
        if (frameIndex >= s_videoFileFrameCount) {
            s_seekingIndex = 0;
            s_seek = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this worked. I could play the video file with stable playback speed. But still had some lag when seeking manually.

Comment: this has nothing to do with streaming. this is **seeking** in video files. I've revised your question. -- your big mistake in the first variant is seeking every time. seeking is costly and rarely accurate. if you're lucky, OpenCV notices trivial seeks and ignores them. -- **do not** make "a video player" with OpenCV. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for video decoding. its video I/O facilities are a bare minimum viable basis, nothing more. if you do, be aware of its limitations, and the technical limitations of video reading in general (seeking).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your support. As your said, my questions was about "seeking" frame from the video file. And I also has some problem with "streaming" (handling frame buffer and showing them with synchronized time). Could you explain more about the "limitations" of OpenCV? If it's about offered only poor functions, I'm willing to implement others. What things should I consider if I wanna video player like "VLC" or something?

Comment: to make a VLC clone, you need: a GUI library like Qt and a video I/O library like ffmpeg (though VLC uses its own, libVLC). -- OpenCV always reads and converts any video input into BGR, because that is OpenCV's native pixel format. ffmpeg's has been weirdly "documented" for a long time, so whatever seeking OpenCV can do isn't always working right.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Since I have to do image processing for each frame of the video, I need to be able to handle the frame data as RGB(or other color space) in C++ code. This is why I implemented my task with OpenCV. Given all frames from video are still treated as cv::Mat in OpenCV, is it worth importing ffmpeg library to my project for video playback and indexing etc.? Your experienced advice saves me. Thanks.

Comment: why do you think that you need seeking? just read frames in order. -- if you _really need_ seeking, check whether opencv actually has trouble with your video or not, and do not seek unnecessarily (reading successive frames should not involve seeking). if OpenCV has trouble with your video, use ffmpeg to convert it to MJPEG, and check again. if that still doesn't work, you have to use ffmpeg for reading, and you'll have to fight with ffmpeg's API to seek.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Ok. I understood what should I care. Thank you for all your assistance.